# Auto install Twitter background image/cover by users

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working on a website contains a collection of Backgrounds and cover pictures. Can I know how can I let users install the backgrounds in their Twitter profile?

Answer (score 0):

The user will need to authenticate with your website, then you will need to use the API call as per the documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/account/update_profile_background_image